# why my dropdown menu not working on some page

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, drop-down-menu

I tried to learn django a few day ago and make a simple website use that, but for a reason my dropdown in home page didn't work but in another page it's work properly.
Here my html template for that

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
    {% for category in links %}
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ category.get_url }}">{{category.category_name}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

and here my code for django urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.store, name='store'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.store, name='product_by_category'),
]
```

and here my code for links references

```
def menu_links(request):
    links = Category.objects.all()
    return dict(links = links)
```

i don't know why in my home page the dropdown button didn't work but in another page it work. i tried to find on my navbar templates and i think there is no problem there but the dropdown still not working and i tried to find on settings.py(to check installation app) but i did it

views.py

```
def home(request):
    products = Product.objects.all().filter(is_available = True)
    
    context = {
        'products' : products,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

anyone have idea where the problem is?

Comment: please show your views file.

Comment: is that enough @KhushalJangid?

Comment: Do you have a `base.html` template?

Comment: @MarcusAurelius where are you returning the `links` dictionary in the context of the home view ?

Comment: @KhushalJangid to context_proccesors in category app

Comment: @Danny of course

Answer (score 0):

The reason why my dropdown not work in some page is because i'm include header tag in my `home.html`, even it's already in my `base.html` template
If someone have similar problem please check your page maybe you make some mistake like me